# iMac forgets brightness

Tags: display

When I set my brightness on a 27'' iMac (2011) next time it boots up, it's dimmed. I switched off the ambient sensor, so this shouldn't be the problem. The connected Cinema Display remembers the brightness correctly.

Had anyone the same problem and found a solution?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running, and which brightness level do you have it set on?

Comment: Snow Leopard with all updates applied. For testing purposes I have tried to set it to maximum, but it returns to three or four ( I must reboot to look for the exact level )

Comment: The exact level it reverts to is three. If I remove the two Cinema Displays attached, it reverts to six. The Cinema Displays aren't affected by this behavior.

Comment: Try setting it one or two levels below maximum and restart. I know that people have said if it's set to the max or min level that can happen. If you still have the same result there's a couple more things you can try. I could make a tiny script that will automatically boost it up where you want it whenever you restart, etc. if you run out of possible possibilities.

Comment: Tried to set it to a value lower than max and rebooted. Reverted back. I'm going to test that tomorrow with the Cinemadisplays disconnected.

Comment: Tested with Cinema Displays disconnected. No change in behavior other than the value it's reverting to changed.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I double checked Energy settings which has options for adjusting brightness, but settings for this have been disabled and it stills dims.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard a few people complain of brightness resetting on reboot. Traditionally brightness settings are stored in the PRAM, which you can reset via <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> on booting. I would be interested to see if it gets "stuck" on a brightness setting that you do not wish to have after resetting the PRAM.

Comment: Does not changed the behavior. Rebooted and hold down the key combination ( it rebooted again ). Then set my desired brightness, rebooted and the same problem again.